# Apigee is down "code": "CLASSIFICATION_FAILED"

Tags: apigee

i am receving classfication failures for requests that are deployed on apigee :

```
{
    "fault": {
        "faultstring": "Classification failed for host intigral-api-prod.apigee.net",
        "detail": {
            "code": "CLASSIFICATION_FAILED"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: we are having prolems on our organization exculsivley, every thing works when i log in with another organization.

Answer (score 1):

The CLASSIFICATION_FAILED error usually means that one component of the request path is not correct.

The request path is comprised of:

```
{scheme}//{host}/{proxyBasePath}/proxyPathSuffix
```

The **scheme** is "http" or "https".

The **host** is the host alias that corresponds to the virtual host.  In your case, the host is *intigral-api-prod.apigee.net*

Given that your as using that host, your API Proxy *should* be deployed to the environment *prod*.

So your request path begins with:

```
http(s)://intigral-api-prod.apigee.net/{proxyBasePath}
```

Check the following:

(1) The scheme (http, https) is allowed in your API Proxy; that is; it is    included in the *ProxyEndpoint HTTPProxyConnection VirtualHost list* defined in your proxy endpoint.
(2) The API Proxy is deployed to the environment *prod*.
(3) The proxyBasePath portion matches the *ProxyEndpoint HTTPProxyConnection BasePath* defined in your proxy endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification ,am sure that all the three check list that you have mentioned are correct and satisfied on my environment on apigee , the calls sometimes work and sometimes not (and it was working perfectly for 4 months until yesterday ) something is failing in the apigee layer, this is very frustrating . myorganization id is "intigral-api"

Answer (score 0):

Also check that your proxy is actually deployed in the environment you're accessing. If you've made a mistake in your design/code, it will often undeploy.

Answer (score 0):

We got the same error for many times because of the proxy is not deployed into the server properly.